# Xubuntu installation on Lenovo Ideapad leads to black screen

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ideapad

After so said successfully installing Xubuntu by USB stick on my Ideapad the installation guide asked me to perform a restart. This restart leaded to a black screen without any courser or options just a black screen. I don't know what to do as i don't have any options.

I would be very happy for any ideas, as It seems like I just don't have any options.

Laptop model: Lenovo ideapad 110S
Xubuntu:  Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: one more information. the screen is on and black, power and battery lights are on. every some minutes the screen goes off (also black but off), the power lamp goes off as well. than some seconds later the power lamp goes on again as well as the screen goes black (on)

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to install it? Apparently you need to do [some preparation on the BIOS before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/printthread.php?t=2350394&pp=10&page=1)

Comment: i just prepared the usb stick and used the install guide i diddnt prepare the bios. i mean i set the boot order so ubuntu and usb are before windows.

Comment: i also wonder if i should switch the laptop off using the power switch, and if i will ever be able again to reach to bios or anywhere else than black screen. not even the lenovo logo is shown to me, it seems the process got stucked before that..

Comment: so i diddnt follow an instruction like this. this can be the fault. i pressed the power button and switched it on again. still same. i cant reach to bios, just reaching to this black screen ... any ideas?